# Fast block production causes Mortality Checking failing with AncientBirthBlock

Tags: transaction-pool

(This might be better as a GitHub issue, but thought I would check here for more context first)
Version: Polkadot SDK v1.1.0

What I am trying to do:

I am running a bunch of e2e tests in parallel on a local only, no relay node. To make this faster, I have setup an interval that every 500 milliseconds will make a block if there are transactions in the transaction pool. (See https://github.com/LibertyDSNP/frequency/blob/main/node/service/src/block_sealing.rs#L128-L148 for an example of how that is setup using seconds instead of ms)

However, this is much faster block production than is expected, and I think I have a race condition due to that speed.

Sometimes (not consistently) the run will produce one or more `InvalidTransaction::AncientBirthBlock` revalidation errors.

These errors can only happen in one place: the `CheckMortality` signed extension. (Specifically: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/polkadot-v1.1.0/substrate/frame/system/src/extensions/check_mortality.rs#L83)

Because I have the Hash count set to 4096 and the number of blocks produced is < 200, the situation occurs because of a difference between three things:

1. The block number which says that the transaction is ready
2. Inserting into the storage of the block number to hash
3. The checking of the block number to hash storage

Note I have also checked and the `period` and `phase` match the expected block number.

By adding in some additional logging around the code that inserts into this storage (https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/polkadot-v1.1.0/substrate/frame/system/src/lib.rs#L1385) and the checking of the storage (check_mortality.rs), here are some perhaps helpful logs that lead to some questions.

1. Why is the block 104 being inserted into the storage several times? (Or why is `initialize` being called several times for the same block number?)

   - My guess is that it is writing a different hash, but that shouldn't matter for `CheckMortality` which is just checking existence of the number in the storage.
2. What else might be happening with this storage? Is there a removal that I am missing besides the one in `finalize` (that is current - 4096 and never gets hit)?
3. Other ideas?

Full logs around this (`ERROR` logs with `WIL:` are my added logs): https://gist.github.com/wilwade/c7245e0f50b9f4ca7d3070fee1138e60

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you not just sign the transactions as immortal since its testing only?

Comment: I could, but while I 95% think it is something strange with the test setup and such causing this, I'm worried there is a (very low impact) race condition bug in substrate I'd like to find.

Comment: In the end, I switched to Immortal as Oliver suggested. Still wonder about the issue however. Feels like a possibility of a race condition.